# How do I maintain session or cookies in ios?

Tags: ios, session, cookies, ios7, parse-platform

I am using Parse as a backend to register users and also storing that data on the phone via Core Data (in case I can't reach Parse, the Core Data user/email system will work for signing in).  How do I maintain state in ios? Is there a proper way with sessions and cookies like the web design pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Parser maintain your session. 
https://www.parse.com/questions/rest-api-session-token-destroy-user-logout

1. In case: your data in parser using PFUser

   ```
   if (![PFUser currentUser]) { 
       //login
   }
   ```
2. In case: your data not using PFUser: you should refer https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#users-login
   login with RestAPI

Comment: true but wondering if I lose internet connection on my app, say I'm on an airplane and want to use no internet and what's in core data, does parse still work?

Comment: Parser SDK support cached query, why you need use a coredata ? In your case, you should try [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/blob/master/Reachability.h) to check connection before request to Parse.

Answer (score 0):

iOS have `NSUserDefault` that work similar to session in web. You can use it to store or get value. For Example :

```
// store some value
NSUserDefaults *session = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[session setObject:someValue forKey:@"data"];
[defaults synchronize];

// fetch some value
NSUserDefaults *session = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"Data : %@", [session objectForKey:@"data"]);
```

This is some good reference about how to use `NSUserDefault` http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the [PFUser currentUser] whether or not it is online, it will simply access the last saved information.

I say save your time and just use Parse's built in persistent storage.

You can even cache queries to access offline.